# What is Pack Flow?

Tags: aircraft-design

I have heard of something in the Air Conditioning panel called pack flow. I heard that it adjust the flow of pack and Lo is 85% NORM 100% and Hi is like 110% or something like that but I just don't understand what is it adjusting. It is the pressure? I have also heard of ECON FLOW, I heard it saves air correct?

Comment: It adjusts the quantity of air (per unit of time = flow) going into the cabin.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the cooling system. It controls the quantity of the air that goes from pneumatic system into the air conditioning unit - simplified version